# python - randomly choose from list

Tags: python, list, random

I have an issue with my code. I made a list where i have cities and their postcodes listed. The script is supposed to be a web automation that randomly chooses a city and its postcode. It has to enter the city in one input field and postcode in another one. My code looks like this and the problem is that it chooses city randomly, but it doesn't select postcode in other field, instead it chooses another random city.

```
from webbot import Browser
import random

d = {'Presov':'08001', 'Zilina':'01001', 'Nove Zamky':'94062'}

web.type((random.choice(list(d))) , into='City')
web.type('Netherlands' , into='State, Province, or Region')
web.type((random.choice(list(d))) , into='Postal Code')
```

Comment: Yeah, well, you're picking a random value twice. You'll want to pick a random *key* once, then use that randomly picked key to get the *value* from `d`.

Comment: `list(d)` only gives you key. Use `list(d.items())`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose the random key and then get the postcode.

```
import random

d = {'Presov':'08001', 'Zilina':'01001', 'Nove Zamky':'94062'}

random_city = random.choice(list(d))
postcode = d[random_city]
print(random_city, postcode)

# alternatively

random_city, postcode = random.choice(list(d.items()))
print(random_city, postcode)

# and then
web.type(random_city, into='City')
web.type('Netherlands' , into='State, Province, or Region')
web.type(postcode, into='Postal Code')
```

Comment: that makes sense but how would i put it into the web.type code?

Comment: here you have, if that solves your issue please mark it as solved